# Apply Method with Implicits Partially

Tags: scala

Given the following method:

```
scala> def f(x: Int)(implicit y: Int, z: Int) = x + y + z
f: (x: Int)(implicit y: Int, implicit z: Int)Int
```

I can define an implicit, and then apply it.

```
scala> implicit val x: Int = 5
x: Int = 5

scala> f(10)
res0: Int = 20
```

But, evidently, I cannot only specify a single implicit argument:

```
scala> f(10)(y = 10)
<console>:10: error: not enough arguments for method f: 
    (implicit y: Int, implicit z: Int)Int.
Unspecified value parameter z.
              f(10)(y = 10)
                   ^
```

Is it possible to specify an implicit argument, i.e. `y`, but leave `z` to implicit resolution?

Answer (score 2):

**You can use the [`implicitly` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.Predef$@implicitly[T]%28implicite:T%29:T)** to satisfy the parameter list's requirement:

```
scala> f(10)(y = 10, implicitly)
res0: Int = 25
```

As it is a part of `Predef`, it's available without any import statement.

Comment: Nice catch. But it would be nicer to pass positional `implicitly` before named `y = 10`, as `f(10)(z = 10, implicitly)` would not compile.

Comment: @Odomontois : yep, and the named argument is pretty much superfluous at this point - however, I wanted to present the answer as close to the question's example as possible.